# Wordpress Permalinks 404 error

Tags: permalinks

Using Default Permalink Settings '/?p=123' works fine for me for every single page and it shows website urls like " ://mywebsite/solutions/?page_id=580"
but

When i changed it to /%postname%/ or to any other category other then the default settings for permalinks  it gives me this error" error page not found "

my .htaccess settings page in root folder is this way

```
  #BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  #END WordPress
```

Thanks and any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled at all? Are you running on apache? is the 404 page is a wordpress page or a general server page?

Comment: 404 wordpress page, I tried installing fresh plugin of quiz master on another wordpress site and the permalinks works fine from ugly to preety, meaning my htaccess file and stuff is fine, the problem is now in the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to replace .htaccess with the following? It looks like you've installed WordPress in a subfolder called *solutions*.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /solutions/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /solutions/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: my site is in root of wordpress but anyway I tried this too.I tried installing fresh plugin of quiz master on another wordpress site and the permalinks works fine from ugly to preety, meaning my htaccess file and stuff is fine, the problem is now in the plugin itself

Comment: Glad that you've fixed it. Would you like to +1 my answer?

Comment: no havent fixed, still the same mess dude

Comment: what i am saying is my .htaccess is fine , problem is with plugin codes somewhere